# runtime isn't writable by PHP. Please fix that

Tags: error-message, permissions

I keep getting the error:

```
mydomain.com/craft/storage/runtime isn't writable by PHP. Please fix that.
```

I am running Redhat, and have set the folder permissions to 777, any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What user:group owns that folder and what user:group is Apache running as?  Do you have any openbase_dir restrictions in place?

Comment: You should never run anything at 777, especially app files.

Comment: This is not going to be an issue of permissions — it’s an issue of ownership. You need to look at which user:group owns that directory, and I’m guessing it’s owned by root? Also, as mentioned it’s a bad idea to set the permissions to 777.